# Terminating Python processes using terminate() in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing

I have a recursive function:

```
def generateCategory(url,level,id,lock)
    #url(string) , level (int), id (Value:shared memory), Lock (Semaphore)

    if level == 5:
        return              #The child process should terminate here right?

    #code here

    for i in range(5):
        Process(target=fn, args =('abc',level+1,id,lock)).start()

    return                  #Here, according to my understanding, the parent process should terminate leaving the child process as an orphan (since I didn't use join)
```

If I am not wrong, some of the processes aren't terminating. I suspect that the same might be happening because the return after the for loop doesn't work as I expect. Instead, it waits until all the child processes are done. I looked into the terminate() command. However, in order for it to work for me, I must terminate a process within itself.

```
self.terminate()
```

seems to give an error.

There is another slight complication.
I am using Value (shared memory) and a Lock (Semaphore) in the code. I have checked the code thoroughly and can confirm that no thread terminates while holding any resource.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of your `Processes`, maybe

```
processes = [Process(target=fn, args=('abc',level+1,id,lock)) for i in range(5)]
```

and then start them

```
[p.start() for p in processes]
```

and you can then get hold of them to terminate whenever you like

```
[p.terminate() for p in processes]
```

You could return `processes` from your function if you need to handle this termination elsewhere.